# Jenkins - Email-ext plugin - Templates

Tags: email, plugins, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I am using the Jenkins plugin called [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) and I want to get Jenkins to send an email generated from the [html.jelly](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/html.jelly) template which is located in $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates. The email should be always send when the code of a specific repo is built.

I have configured the email-ext plugin to always send the email when that specific repo is built and in the field 'Default Pre-send Script' I have referenced the template: ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"}

However, when Jenkins builds the code the jelly script fails with the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.

   <STYLE>
   ^

1 error
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:359)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:142)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:161)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:846)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:550)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:526)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:503)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:302)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:281)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:578)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.executePresendScript(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:450)
at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.sendMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:311)
at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:297)
at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:244)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:192)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1764)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

Do you have any solutions to solve this problem?
I  appreciate any help, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please provide Jenkins and Email-ext version numbers.

Try to put ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"} in the email "Default Content"
That should work.